# SitecoreJSS 9.1 release date and SitecoreJSS 9 limitations

Tags: sitecore

I am going to use SitecoreJSS to develop a website.
- When SitecoreJSS 9.1 would be released?
- what are the limitations and restrictions of using Sitecore JSS 9.0(Tech Preview 4)?

Answer (score -1):

Release date information is not appropriate for StackOverflow. You may want to ask this in the [Sitecore Slack community](https://sitecorechat.slack.com) instead (Join via form here: http://siteco.re/SitecoreSlack)

However, for your question on limitations. When JSS is fully released with 9.1, a 9.0-compatible version will also be made available. That version is fully supported.

If you work instead with the Tech Preview 4 that you mention, you will be using preview software which may not be compatible with the GA version of 9.1 and also will not be supported by the Sitecore support team.